# Is there an app I can use to centralize all my healthcare information?

Tags: web-apps, health

I'm only 32 and I've already developed a pretty beefy medical history. Luckily my memory is good enough that I don't need to write everything down. But at this rate I doubt I can rely on just my memory once I hit 40 or 50.

I remember Microsoft had a HealthVault feature which they recently discontinued. And I know Apple Health tracks a bunch of metrics. But when you go to a healthcare provider they usually have their own healthcare information management (HIM) system. If you're lucky, multiple providers will share a common HIM for payment and visit notes. But if they don't, is there an app or anything that can sync all these things? Just like Mint dashboards all your financial accounts, is there something that can do that for your healthcare accounts?

Comment: Welcome Herman! Getting older isn't for the faint of heart!  I've tagged your question as a web-app, because I think that's what you are looking for.  If I'm mistaken, you can just edit the tags or ask me for help.  Are you looking for a gratis (free of cost) service, or something paid?  BTW, what I do is keep a text file with all the info and sync it manually.  Before a doctor visit, I usually print it out for quick reference and note-taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several solutions are suggested by [this](https://www.cnet.com/health/how-to-keep-track-of-your-medical-records/#) CNET article. The following are some apps

1. [Wanggi](https://wanngi.com/)
2. [My Medical](https://www.mymedicalapp.com/)
3. The Apple Health App via the Records feature
4. [Hixny](https://www.hixny.org/individuals/)

There are also some primary-care subscription services recommended by the article.